# changing class selector not working on appended items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following ragged array (actual one is bigger, this is just for illustration):

```
var myarray = [
[
 ['k1', [] ],
 ['k2', ['l1', 'l2'] ],
 ['k3', [] ],
],

[
 ['k1', [] ],
 ['k2', ['l1', 'l2', 'l3'] ],
]

];
```

I am trying to dynamically append `<ul>` and `<li>` elements with content taken from `myarray` to existing `<ul>` elements using the following nested loops:

```
var $li1, $li2; 
for ( i = 0, count = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
    for ( k = 0; k < myarray[i].length-1; k++){
        $li1 = $("<li><span>"+myarray[i][k][0]+"</span></li>");
        $li1.appendTo( $('.ulouter')[i] );
        count++;
        if (k == 0) continue; //do not append to first one
        $("<ul class='ulinner'></ul>").appendTo($('.ulouter > li')[count-1]);
        for ( l = 0; l < myarray[i][k][1].length; l++){
            $li2 = $( "<li><span>"+myarray[i][k][1][l]+"</span></li>" );
            $li2.appendTo( $('.ulinner').eq(count-1));
        }
    }
}
```

where the loaded html page already contains a certain number of `<ul class='ulouter'></ul>` elements.

The appending `$("<ul class='ulinner'></ul>").appendTo($('.ulouter > li')[count-1]);` works just fine, and the expected number of `<ul class='ulinner'></ul>` are created in the right place. However, `$li2.appendTo( $('.ulinner').eq(count-1));` does nothing, even though printing the value of `count` gives me the expected value.

If, on the other hand, I use say `$li2.appendTo( $('.ulinner').eq(3));` or any other number, the appending does take place. But the minute I use the variable `count` and change its value within the loop, nothing happens, and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Especially that `count` *does* take the value of 3 at some point, so that it should at least work in some cases.

Note that using `[ ]` instead of `.eq()` makes no difference. Is there any reason why jQuery (using plain javascript selectors does the same thing actually) doesn't recognize the newly appended elements when selected with a changing variable count? I feel like I'm missing something obvious and I can't seem to reproduce that behavior in a codepen-like environment.

Edit: see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOaOOZ
on line 24, the console outputs the value of `count-1` which at some point reaches 1. One would then expect `$li2.appendTo( $('.ulinner').eq(count-1));` to effect the second `.ulinner`, but it doesn't. *However*, if you uncomment line 26, so that `count-1` is simply replaced by 1, then it works. What is going on?

Comment: _"//do not append to first one"_ Is expected value of `count` `1` before `if (k == 0) continue; ?` , though `0` at `$("<ul class='ulinner'></ul>").appendTo($('.ulouter > li')[count-1]);` ? , selecting `li` element at index `0` in collection of `.ulouter > li` elements ?

Comment: see added codepen. @guest271314 I am not quite understanding your question.

Comment: @ephemeral http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbEbqY ? Substituted `$("<ul class='ulinner'></ul>").appendTo($('.ulouter > li')[count]);` for `$("<ul class='ulinner'></ul>").appendTo($('.ulouter > li')[count-1]);` , where `count`:`1` following initial `count++;` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

[JS Fiddle link for dynamic listing](http://jsfiddle.net/yogeshalive/r79eooh2/)

sample code:

```
    var html="";
function inside(events)
  {
    for (i in events) {

      if (typeof events[i] === 'object'){
          html+="<ul>";
        inside(events[i]);
        html+="</ul>";
      }else{
      html+="<li>"+events[i]+"</li>";
      }
    }
  }
  inside(myarray);
$("body").append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append li2 to the ulouter but it should go under the ulinner of its parent li

Just change your last append statement to below, it will work
`$li2.appendTo( $('.ulouter').eq(i).find('li').eq(k).find('.ulinner'));`